# How to make a package visible only within the current lexical scope?

Tags: r, scope

As illustrated by the snippet below, running `require(...)` inside a function affects the enclosing environment:

```
% R --vanilla --quiet
> match('package:ggplot2', search())
[1] NA
> (function () { require(ggplot2) })()
Loading required package: ggplot2
> match('package:ggplot2', search())
[1] 2
```

Is there a way to prevent this?  IOW, is there a way to make a package available only in the current lexical scope, without affecting the output of `search()` in the calling environment?

Comment: Maybe use double colon to access functions without loading? e.g.: `ggplot2::ggplot()` ?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could use `?unloadNamespace` after ending your function? `match('package:ggplot2', search()); (function() { on.exit(unloadNamespace("ggplot2")); require(ggplot2); print(match('package:ggplot2', search())) })(); match('package:ggplot2', search())`